# How can I use the class that is inside a codeSubDirectories in another other codeSubDirectories in Asp.Net

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I want to have separate dlls for each namespace and I want to move each namespace class into codeSubDirectories in App_Code, but the class that is in one directory cant see the class in another directory

I can't add other project to my website to create separate dll and I can't place dependent class into one directory because I have a team that has a class for each other and have public class that all team members must use.

I use this in web config:

```
<codeSubDirectories>
        <add directoryName="dir1" />
        <add directoryName="dir2" />
</codeSubDirectories>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't be done. One project, one DLL/EXE.